# Setting Meta tags for a website

Tags: meta-description, meta-keywords, asp.net-mvc, meta-tags

I have made an Asp.net MVC website and am not well versed about SEO techniques, so I want a little guidance in setting the appropriate meta tags for the website.

My website is dynamic and has two types of Pages: **Category** and **Product**

There are two tables in the database for Category and Product.

Looking into the future, I added these fields beforehand to both the tables :

> -- MetaTitle--MetaDescription--MetaKeywords

On both the Category and Product pages, these values are retrieved and set as following

```
<meta name="description" content="@ViewBag.MetaDescription" />
<meta name="title" content="@ViewBag.MetaTitle" />
<meta name="keywords" content="@ViewBag.MetaKeywords" />
```

For better SEO how will you set up these meta tags. Will you include the site name in all three fields ? Right now, the Product page's MetaTitle, MetaDescription and MetaKeywords don't include the website name.

If possible, can you provide me sample values that should be set for better SEO performance keeping the business name in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of [questions about Meta tags](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta) here and you really should read up on them here to learn more about them. But you will find that you're putting too much time into them for very little return. The meta keywords tag has no SEO value at all. The meta title tag is not used at all (do not confuse that with the `<title>` tag which is very different and very important). The meta description tag does not affect your ranking but can be shown in your search engine listing so it does need to be well written. It shouldn't need the website name in it if the page title already includes that name as the two will obviously will be seen together in the search engines results.